# Get note contents with evernote api in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, evernote

I'm working on my private project using Evernote API and node.js(express.js)

I successfully got an `requestToken` and `accessToken` using jsOAuth Module and I got the note `guid` from `noteMetaData` too.

however, when I use

> noteStore.getNote

function, It continuously fails.
 with this errormessage :

> Error in NodeBinaryHttpTransport.flush: Binary protocol does not support synchronous calls

however I already inserted my callback function.

I checked API Docs but not specific doc for javascript. Arguments are different. I checked what kind of arguments does `noteStore.getNote` wants by logging `Function.length`, but it was 0.

here is my code.

I use express and router is **require('express').Router();**

gb is global object that contains my developer token and secret.

```
router.get('/users',function (request,response){
var parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url);
console.log('search is:'+parsedUrl.search)
client.getAccessToken(
  gb.oauthToken, 
  gb.oauthSecret, 
  getOauthVerifier(parsedUrl.search), 
  function(error, oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, results) {
    if(error) {
      console.log("error\n\n\n");
      console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      console.log('successfully get an access token.');
      var accessedClient = new Evernote.Client({
        token: oauthAccessToken,
        sandbox:true
      })

      var noteStore = accessedClient.getNoteStore("https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note/");
      noteStore.listNotebooks(function(err, notebook){

              var filter = new Evernote.NoteFilter();

              filter.notebookGuid = notebook[0].guid;

              console.log('filter is..',filter);
              var resultSpec = new Evernote.NotesMetadataResultSpec();
              resultSpec.includeTitle = true;
              resultSpec.includeContentLength = true;
              resultSpec.includeCreated = true;
              resultSpec.includeAttributes = true;

              noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 100, resultSpec, function(err, notesMeta) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.error('err',err);
                  }
                  else {

                    console.log("Found "+notesMeta.notes.length+" notes in your default notebook . . .")
                    for (var i in notesMeta.notes) {

                     var noteGuid = notesMeta.notes[i]['guid'];

                     var note = noteStore.getNote(
                        noteGuid,{
                        withContent: true
                        },

                        function(err, results){

                          if(err) return console.error("Error")
                          console.log(results);
                          response.end();
                      })                      
                    }
                  }
              }); 
      })           
  }
);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid question. I found a solution.
All I Needed to do was sticking to the parameter guided in the API docs.

```
noteGuid,{
   var note = noteStore.getNote( true, true, true,true
},

function(err, results){
    if(err)
        return console.error("Error")
    console.log(results);
    response.end();
})
```